# How to calculate the volatility of a equity option spread

Tags: options, volatility, spread, spread-options

I would like to calculate the volatility of an equity option spread with all legs having the same expiration.

Reading *Option Volatility and Pricing 2nd Edition* by Natenberg, Chapter 20, section *Forward Volatility* he writes about calculating the volatility for a calendar spread:

> We need to reduce the volatility until we find the single volatility that will cause the spread to be worth 1.49. Using a computer, we find that the February/March calendar spread has an implied volatility of 25.94 percent.

He proceeds to give instructions for an approximation:

$ \frac{O_{2} - O_{1}}{V_{2} - V_{1}} $

with $O_{2} - O_{1}$ being the price of the spread
and $V_{2} - V_{1}$ being the vega of the spread

How can one combine the volatilities of a spread, specifically a spread where all legs have the same expiration, into a single exact volatility quantity?

Many thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, the example Natenberg gives is a calendar spread, but the answer you seek is for a non-calendar spread: all expiration dates are the same. Is that correct? Actually, the answer to this is quite simple if you accept Black-Scholes: compute the price of the spread as a function of volatility (using Black-Scholes) and then find the volatility(s) that mach the actual price.